# Mapbox : GeoJson Source in Runtime Styling

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Do Mapbox Supports, `GeoJson` source support in Runtime Styling.

I tried same Style (file with two Source 1. `Vector`, 2. `GeoJson`) file with `mapbox-gl-native` and `mapbox-gl-js`.

It was working as expected in Native SDK but it seems mapbox-gl-js is ignoring if source type is GeoJson.

I tried version **0.52**

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely possible. You just need to call `.addSource` on your `map` object before you use that source to generate the style layers. This example shows how the general flow for adding a GeoJson source: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/multiple-geometries/

If you're trying to reference a geojson file, you'll just need to specify that file's URL [via the data field](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources-geojson) of your source object. If you're going that route, the GeoJson file needs to be on the same domain or accessible using [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/).

Here's a quick and dirty code snippet to illustrate what I mean:

```
map.on("load", function() {
    map.addSource("my-geojson-source", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": "path/to/data.geojson"
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "styled-geojson-layer",
        "type": "circle", // this depends on your data & goals
        "source": "my-geojson-source",
        ... // add style things here
    });
});
```

If you get stuck, the library documentation should have everything you need:

- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/examples/
- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources
- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers

Comment: Yes this is happening via data driven styling, but i am trying to achieve using runtime styling . Adding two sources in style file.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. Are you able to share an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem?

Comment: I am preparing it. I will definitely share once ready. Thanks